# I am able to ping a device on a different subnet without passing through a L3 device. How?

Tags: networking, ping, subnet

I have two devices in the same broadcast domain.  My PC and an Avaya IP Control Unit.

My IP is **10.168.10.154/22**.

Avaya Device IP is **192.168.10.99/23**.

I am able to ping this device and don't understand how.

1. The Avaya Device has no gateway set.
2. Even if it did, there are no routes on the Cisco router to any **192.168.x.x** networks.  The switches all have L3 functions turned off.
3. The MAC Address shown from "arp -a" on my PC is the same MAC Address shown in the MAC Address Table of the switch the Avaya Device is connected to.  So I think I can safely assume there is no ARP Proxy.
4. Route Print on my local machine shows: **192.168.10.99 255.255.255.255** On-link **10.168.10.154** 26
5. Tracert shows:  Tracing route to **192.168.10.99** over a maximum of 30 hops

   1 * 1 ms <1 ms **192.168.1.99**

Even more odd, my PC seems to be the only device that can ping the Avaya device.  My PC has one physical interface, and it has no sub-interfaces.  There is a virtual inteface created by VirtualBox, but it resides in the 192.168.56.0/24 network so I'm not sure it's relevant.  Possibly worth mentioning is that this is a MacMini running Bootcamp, so maybe this is a function of Bonjour?

Comment: Are both of these on the same L2 switch (and same VLAN, if you're using those)?  You can ping different networks/masks in this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Route Print on my local machine shows: 192.168.10.99 255.255.255.255 On-link 
>   10.168.10.154 26

That is why, the On-link routes are accessible locally without any gateway, many times they are created when you connect via dial-up (to Avaya device maybe). You have to find out why this route is being created. Maybe it was just a left over or was added manually in the past as a persistent route, Try deleting the route, ping, then reboot and ping to see it was not created again somehow.

Comment: It's possible that any Avaya management software or IP soft phone currently or previously installed on the computer might have put the route there, if such software was ever installed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox In fact I am using Avaya Management software.  Arana I will try that now.

Comment: So was it created on reboot or did you find why that route was there?

Comment: Thank you Arana, it seems that Avaya IP Office Manager created an "on-link route".  I have something new to learn with "on-link routes".  I was worried about a rogue device in my network or rogue setting on my PC.  Thanks again.

Comment: @arana What constitutes "a dialup" connection in this case?  Because it's obviously not a dialup in the traditional sense of a phone modem calling a phone number.

Comment: In the sense of "direct connection" , bridge to a VM, or 3g USB devices,  mostly  "Not by LAN" , some if not all Avaya devices can be managed by dial up, serial or other non LAN connection or have the capability to offer such service, This isn't a rule but most of the times you see those on-link routes , the cause is some of those things, I am not 100% sure but I guess that was setup during software installation, maybe ticked an option that wasn't done in the other PCs, or tried some functions that enabled the route. This happened to me with MERIDIAN equipment software, .

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you have an additional ip address assigned to your NIC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good idea but no, that was the first thing I checked.